# Set Fluent nHibernate PersistenceSpecification using propertySetter

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to explicitly set property values using Fluent nHibernate's PersistenceSpecification

Consider the following:

```
Guid expectedId = Guid.NewGuid();

new PersistenceSpecification<MyClass>(session)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.ID, expectedId , //some delegate here?)
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

In the constructor for MyClass, the ID is set.
However, I'd like to overwrite that in my test, by explicitly setting it to `expectedId`

One of the overloads for `CheckProperty` has a propertySetter delegate, however I can't find any documentation on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.CheckProperty()` will use the second parameter to set it before saving and to compare it after loading again, so it is already setting the expectedId.